# Unable to erase from libstdc++ Policy based data structure

Tags: c++, stl, containers, libstdc++

There is an associated container in C++ which is actually a set (multiset) which can give the order of an element in it in.

Here is how I use the container:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

template <typename T>
using ordered_multiset = tree<T, null_type, less_equal<T>, rb_tree_tag,
                              tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
```

The problem is, I am not able to erase an element from it:

```cpp
ordered_multiset<int> s;
s.insert(0);
s.erase(0);

cout << s.order_of_key(1); // returns number of elements less than x

// Outputs: 1
```

The strange part is that if you replace `less_equal` with `less`, then you would be able to do the job without a problem, actually if you use the container as a multiset, then you won't be able to erase elements from it, but there is no problem when you use it as a set.

- What is causing the problem?
- How can I solve the problem?

**Note: Please don't suggest solving the problem in way of using another container. That's not a solution.**

Comment: Why not use `std::multiset`?

Comment: @Kerndog73 Because of the use of function `order_of_key`. In multiset doing this job is O(n).

Comment: Why are you using `std::less_equal` when `std::less` is expected (it's the default)?

Comment: @Kerndog73 Because I need a multiset, not a set. Duplication of number in the container.

Comment: So the data structure you're using is actually a set but you're using `std::less_equal` to fake a multiset? That doesn't sound safe

Comment: @Kerndog73 I would be happy if you provide an alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205926/discussion-between-amirali-and-kerndog73).

Comment: rather than rely on `using namespace std;using namespace __gnu_pbds;`, be explicit about the namespace your are talking about. `ordered_multiset` is not part of c++, but of some non-common extension

Comment: @UmNyobe `ordered_multiset` is defined on the first code.

Comment: `The problem is, I am not able to erase an element from it`. People cannot answer this question if they can't find the reference.

Comment: "Note: Please don't suggest solving the problem in way of using another container. That's not a solution." **any** solution is going to involve a different container, even if its some other instantiation of `tree`

Comment: @UmNyobe Have you read the line `using ordered_multiset = tree< ... ` on my first code in the question?

Comment: @Caleth It's ok to provide an alternative which does the job of `order_of_key` in O(1).

Comment: I can't find where the claim of `O(1)` comes from for `order_of_key`, but I am very suspicious of it, given that lookup is `O(log(n))`

Comment: I have. But there are conflicting statements in your question, and the simple insert-erase should have worked. but it doesn't. So you broke the library contract in some way, and to be able to say in which way we need the library contract. which is not the standard library. As @Caleth said, the complexity claim seems wrong.

Comment: @Caleth I don't know, it may be logarithmic. I have heard that it works in constant time but I am not able to find any reliable source which says that.

Comment: Not being able to find documentation is another reason not to use this library and instead using the standard library

Comment: @Caleth Even if it is logarithmic, it is much better than linear. That's way I'm not using `std::multiset`.

Comment: linear is still better than unimplemented, which is better than unimplementable

Comment: @Caleth You're right about the complexity of `order_of_key`, it's logarithmic.

Answer (score 6):

Using `std::less_equal`, there's no way to know if two elements are equivalent. `std::set` uses the expression `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` to determine whether `a` and `b` are equivalent. This works if you use a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) like `std::less` but fails when you use `std::less_equal`. `5` and `5` are equivalent but `!(5 <= 5) && !(5 <= 5)` is `false`. So the erase fails.

In short, you can't just turn a set into a multiset using `std::less_equal`.

---

[@Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59732192) has described a way of using `std::multiset` and doing the search in linear time. You can determine the order in logarithmic time by keeping the order for each element.

```
template <typename Value>
struct ordered_value {
  size_t order;
  Value value;
};

template <typename Value>
using ordered_multiset = std::multiset<ordered_value<Value>>;
```

The problem with this is that you have to update the order each time you insert or erase (which is linear). Are you sure that the container you're using does the operation in constant time? That kind of seems impossible to me.

The way that the ordering statistic is implemented in a red-black tree is actually pretty similar. There's some extra information in each node that is updated whenever you insert or erase. The point is, **this is pretty close to the best you can do** without going to all the trouble of making your own red-black tree.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same problem and think I found a not so elegant but useful solution.

You can make your own `erase` function like this:

```
void myerase(ordered_set &t, int v){
    int rank = t.order_of_key(v);//Number of elements that are less than v in t
    ordered_set::iterator it = t.find_by_order(rank); //Iterator that points to the (rank+1)th element in t
    t.erase(it);
}
```

Since `order_of_key`, `find_by_order` and the standard `erase` are all `O(log(N))`, `myerase` should also be `O(log(N))`.

Here is the code snippet I used to test it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp> 
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp> 

using namespace __gnu_pbds; 
using namespace std;

typedef tree<int,null_type,less_equal<int>,rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;

void myerase(ordered_set &t, int v){
    int rank = t.order_of_key(v);//Number of elements that are less than v in t
    ordered_set::iterator it = t.find_by_order(rank); //Iterator that points to the (rank+1)th element in t
    t.erase(it);
}

void printOrderedSet(ordered_set s){
    //Function to show the contents of the set
    for(auto it=s.begin(); it!=s.end(); it++){
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    //Create an ordered_set t with the numbers 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
    ordered_set t;
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
        t.insert(i/2);
    }
    printOrderedSet(t); //output: 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
    
    myerase(t, 3);
    printOrderedSet(t); //output: 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 4 4

    myerase(t, 3);
    printOrderedSet(t); //output: 0 0 1 1 2 2 4 4

    myerase(t, 0);
    printOrderedSet(t); //output: 0 1 1 2 2 4 4

    myerase(t, 1);
    printOrderedSet(t); //output: 0 1 2 2 4 4
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the real problem was already pointed out (you shouldn't use less_equal as a comparator). However, recently I had a similar problem, when I was solving the problems from the CSES problemset. I found a pretty simple, but working solution (replace int with integer type that can hold enough elements):

```
template <typename T>
using ordered_multiset = tree<pair<T, int>, null_type, less_equal<T>, rb_tree_tag,
                          tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
int timer = 0; // the number of elements inserted

ordered_multiset<int> st;
// to insert do
st.insert({value, timer});
timer++;

// to erase elements you can do this
auto it = st.lower_bound({value, 0});
if (it != st.end() && it->first == value)
    st.erase(it);
```

What's more, in a lot of competitive programming related problems you usually insert elements from an array, so you can take the indexes from the position in array, and erasing them becomes easier

Answer (score 1):

> What is causing the problem?

You haven't supplied a [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) to `tree`. Your program is ill-formed.

> How can I solve the problem?

Use `std::multiset<T>` and

```
template<typename Set, typename Key>
size_t order_of_key(const Set & set, const Key & key)
{
    return std::distance(set.begin(), set.lower_bound(key));
}
```

Comment: If you mean `std::multiset`, then I can't use a multiset becuase I need the function `order_of_key` which is not available in multiset container.

Comment: `std::distance` is in O(n), n = distance of the two element.

Comment: Would it actually have to be `upper_bound` to get the first element greater than the one searched for? The question is a little unclear in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an iterator to the erase function worked for me. 
If it is not convenient to find the iterator, I believe `pbds.erase(pbds.find_by_order(your_order)` should work. 
If you do not know the order a priori, you can do something like `pbds.erase(pbds.find_by_order(pbds.order_of_key(your_key)))`

Comment: All of these options work in `O(log (size of pbds) )`.

Answer (score -1):

**We can erase by passing an iterator in erase function  **
Here is my snapped:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjoSW.png)

Comment: Please do not upload images of code or errors.